# Not able to lookup EJB ,Not able to deploy EJB in WebLogic server 12c

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

When I run project without ejb-jar.xml on weblogic 12c,it runs fine...
But when I include this ejb-jar.xml it gives me error

> "Substituted for missing class In EJB ejb3.1, both the remote home and remote component interface must be specified. Currently, only one of them is specified."

and when I used same ejb-jar.xml on Jboss 6.4, here the project run fine.

Please assist.

---

**Hello.java**

```
 package com.end;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
    public interface Hello{ 
    public String hello(String h);
}
```

---

**HelloBean.java**

```
package com.end;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements Hello {

public String hello(String h) {
System.out.println("server hello"); 
return "client " + h + "  !";
    }
}
```

---

**Client code
Print.java**

```
package com.end;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
public class Print 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hel = null;
        Date d = new Date();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(d);
        Properties p = new Properties();

        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7005");

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);
            hel = (Hello) ctx.lookup("Hello#com.end.Hello");
            System.out.println(hel.hello(strDate));
            } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now the **ejb-jar.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                        <ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <enterprise-beans>

        <session>

            <ejb-name>HelloBean</ejb-name>

            <remote>com.end.Hello</remote>

            <ejb-class>com.end.HelloBean</ejb-class>

            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>

            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

        </session>

    </enterprise-beans>

</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: shouldn't `?xml` be `<?xml`?

Comment: Why are you using an `ejb-jar.xml` since its not required?!

Comment: I tried with annotations...but i also want to try with ejb-jar.xml.